# Getting unwanted 0 in the front of array

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am working with Ajax, as request is success but not getting proper json response.
In Response its getting like this `0{.....}`

What is the solution to this?

MY PHP Code-

```
<?php
if ($f == 'register') {
    if (!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = '';
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    }
    if (!empty($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
        $_COOKIE['user_id'] = '';
        unset($_COOKIE['user_id']);
        setcookie('user_id', null, -1);
        setcookie('user_id', null, -1, '/');
    }

    if (empty($_POST['firstName']) || empty($_POST['lastName']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['confirm_pwd'])) {
        $errors = $error_icon . "Please fill all details !";
    } else {
        if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
            $errors = $error_icon . "Please enter your email !";
        }
        if (Br_EmailExists($_POST['email']) === true) {
            $errors = $error_icon . 'email_exists';
        }
        if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors = $error_icon . 'email_invalid_characters';
        }
        if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6) {
            $errors = $error_icon . 'password_short';
        }
        if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_pwd']) {
            $errors = $error_icon . 'password_mismatch';
        }
    }
    $profile_pic = "";
    if (isset($_FILES['profileUpload'])) {
        $profile_pic = Br_upload_profile($_FILES['profileUpload']);
    } else {
        $profile_pic = $br['config']['theme_url'] . '/userimgs/defaultuser.png';
    }
    $field_data = array();
    if (empty($errors)) {
        $activate = ($br['config']['emailValidation'] == '1') ? '0' : '1';
        $code = md5(rand(1111, 9999) . time());
        $re_data  = array(
            'email' => Br_Secure($_POST['email'], 0),
            'fname' => Br_Secure($_POST['firstName'], 0),
            'lname' => Br_Secure($_POST['lastName'], 0),
            'password' => $_POST['password'],
            'v_code' => Br_Secure($code, 0),
            'src' => 'site',
            'lastseen' => time(),
            'active' => Br_Secure($activate),
            'birthday' => '0000-00-00',
            'profile_pic' => Br_Secure($profile_pic, 0),
        );
        // if ($gender == 'female') {
        //     $re_data['avatar'] = "upload/photos/f-avatar.jpg";
        // }


        // if (!empty($_POST['phone_num'])) {
        //     $re_data['phone_number'] = Br_Secure($_POST['phone_num']);
        // }
        // $in_code  = (isset($_POST['invited'])) ? Br_Secure($_POST['invited']) : false;
        // if (empty($_POST['phone_num'])) {
        //     $register = Br_RegisterUser($re_data, $in_code);
        // }
        // else{
        //     if($activate == 1){
        //        $register = Br_RegisterUser($re_data, $in_code);
        //     }
        //     else{
        //         $register = true;
        //     }
        // }

        $registers = Br_RegisterUser($re_data);

        //$registers = true;
        if ($registers === true) {
            if ($activate == 1) {
                $data  = array(
                    'status' => 200,
                    'message' => $success_icon . 'Successfully Joined'
                );
                $login = Br_Login($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
                if ($login === true) {
                    $session             = Br_CreateLoginSession(Br_UserIdFromEmail($_POST['email']));
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $session;
                    setcookie("user_id", $session, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
                }
                //$data['location'] = Br_SeoLink('index.php?link1=start-up');
                $data['location'] = Br_SeoLink('index.php?link1=welcome');
                if ($br['config']['membership_system'] == 1) {
                    $data['location'] = Br_SeoLink('index.php?link1=go-pro');
                }
            } else if ($br['config']['sms_or_email'] == 'mail') {
                $br['user']        = $_POST;
                $br['code']        = $code;
                $body              = Br_LoadPage('emails/activate');
                $send_message_data = array(
                    'from_email' => $br['config']['siteEmail'],
                    'from_name' => $br['config']['siteName'],
                    'to_email' => $_POST['email'],
                    'to_name' => $_POST['username'],
                    'subject' => 'account_activation',
                    'charSet' => 'utf-8',
                    'message_body' => $body,
                    'is_html' => true
                );
                $send              = Br_SendMessage($send_message_data);
                $errors            = $success_icon . 'successfully_joined_verify_label';
                if ($br['config']['membership_system'] == 1) {
                    $session             = Br_CreateLoginSession(Br_UserIdFromUsername($_POST['username']));
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $session;
                    setcookie("user_id", $session, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
                }
            } else if ($br['config']['sms_or_email'] == 'sms' && !empty($_POST['phone_num'])) {
                $random_activation = Br_Secure(rand(11111, 99999));
                $message           = "Your confirmation code is: {$random_activation}";

                if (Br_SendSMSMessage($_POST['phone_num'], $message) === true) {
                    $register = Br_RegisterUser($re_data, $in_code);
                    $user_id           = Br_UserIdFromUsername($_POST['username']);
                    $query             = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, "UPDATE " . T_USERS . " SET `sms_code` = '{$random_activation}' WHERE `user_id` = {$user_id}");
                    $data = array(
                        'status' => 300,
                        'location' => Br_SeoLink('index.php?link1=confirm-sms?code=' . $code)
                    );
                    if ($br['config']['membership_system'] == 1) {
                        $session             = Br_CreateLoginSession(Br_UserIdFromUsername($_POST['username']));
                        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $session;
                        setcookie("user_id", $session, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
                    }
                } else {
                    $errors = $error_icon . 'failed_to_send_code_email';
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($field_data)) {
            $user_id = Br_UserIdFromEmail($_POST['email']);
        }
    }
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    if (isset($errors)) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'errors' => $errors
        ));
    } else {
        echo (json_encode(array(
            'data' => $data
        )));
    }
    exit();
}
```

this the the file which is called by ajax for user registration.
But its not giving proper response.
Where its working fine for error response.
And not working for succeed response.

```
$this.ajaxForm({
            url: Br_Ajax_Requests_File() + '?f=register',
            beforeSend: function() {
                <?php if (0) { //$br['config']['password_complexity_system'] == 1 
                ?>
                    if ($('.helper-text .length').hasClass('valid') && $('.helper-text .lowercase').hasClass('valid') && $('.helper-text .uppercase').hasClass('valid') && $('.helper-text .special').hasClass('valid')) {
                        $this.find('button').attr("disabled", true);
                        $this.find('.add_wow_loader').addClass('btn-loading');
                    } else {
                        $state.html("<?php echo ('complexity_requirements'); ?>");
                        return false;
                    }
                <?php } else { ?>
                    //$this.find('button').attr("disabled", true);
                    //$this.find('.add_wow_loader').addClass('btn-loading');
                    return true
                <?php } ?>
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.status == 200) {
                    $state.addClass('success');
                    $state.html('<?php echo 'welcome'; ?>');
                    $this.find('.add_wow_loader').removeClass('btn-loading');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location.href = data.location;
                    }, 1000);
                } else if (data.status == 300) {
                    $state.html('<?php echo 'redirecting'; ?>');
                    window.location.href = data.location;
                } else {
                    $this.find('button').attr("disabled", false);
                    $this.find('.add_wow_loader').removeClass('btn-loading');
                    $state.html(data.errors);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
```

This is the ajax code. But at console log....its not showing anything

[Ajax Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UfGg.jpg) [image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: share your php code instead of image

Comment: i just want to know why 0 is coming if the front of response.

Comment: Scroll up in the code, the output is clearly from _before_ the JSON output.

Comment: _"i just want to know"_ - it doesn't matter whether that is "all" you want to know right now, that does not change a thing about how you are supposed to ask questions here. Please go and do as you were told, and edit the question to contain the code in text form (properly formatted) first of all now.

Comment: Now, Question contain whole code. Now pls help me

Comment: You might also want to check if any of your numerous `Br_*` functions echoes something

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have issue with condition which checks `$f`

Try to get value from request first then check your response. Add below code at top of the file.

`$f = $_GET['f'];`

Comment: This still doesn't explain the extra zero, at most this would display a notice

Comment: @DarkBee In description Brijesh mentioned that 'But at console log....its not showing anything'. Also display warning is based on configuration

Comment: The screenshot of OP's console def. shows otherwise